# How can I split the data over multiple lines in a JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

How can I put each line of the host in the message body? I work with a `JTextArea`.

```
String host = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName().toString();
texto_recepcion.setText(host + texto_recepcion.getText() + dpRecepcion.getAddress() + " " + mensaje_recibido + "\n");
```

How it is now:

[image]

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do. Could you provide a little more information?

Comment: I'm doing a chat show and I would like the following 

"host / ip / message".

Each message sent by the user, but my host overrides 

For example :

1st message sent = host / ip / message
2nd message sent = host / host / ip / message
ip / message

Comment: @YoelMacia: I have made some changes to your post that might benefit you as learning material for future questions. More specifically: stick to the point in your question. Your problem didn't have anything to do with hosts of multicasting, it was about splitting the data (it didn't matter what the data represented) over multiple lines in a `JTextArea`. By being to the point you will get more appropriate responses. Same goes for the tagging: tag the tags that are relevant to the problem. Lastly: use backticks to signify a code element, it's easier to read english and code combined that way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append Text to JTextArea on Multiple Lines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28307990/append-text-to-jtextarea-on-multiple-lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve my question with append function.

```
String host = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName().toString();

texto_recepcion.append(host); // ***Use the function append for solve the problem***

texto_recepcion.setText(texto_recepcion.getText() + dpRecepcion.getAddress() + " " + mensaje_recibido + "\n");
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add the newline character "\n" to the beginning of the string?

```
texto_recepcion.setText("\n" + host + texto_recepcion.getText() + dpRecepcion.getAddress() + " " + mensaje_recibido);
```

Comment: No, this is your result ... <br/>

MacBook-Pro-de-Yoel.local
MacBook-Pro-de-Yoel.local/192.168.1.132 first message
/192.168.1.132 second message

Comment: What kind of control is `texto_recepcion`? Is it a textbox w/o multiline?

Comment: JTextArea but already i resolve the problem. Use append function.

Comment: @YoelMacia it would be great if you marked this question as solved and post the solution for future reference.