# Append Text to JTextArea on Multiple Lines?

Tags: java, string, swing, jtextarea

I have a string with multiple numbers, when printed out it looks something like this:

> 2 
>   4 
>   5 
>   10 
>   20 
>   25 
>   50

However, when I append the string to a JTextArea it looks like this:

> 24510202550

How can I make the JTextArea look like the ouput with the numbers on seperate lines? Thanks!

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: "I have a string with multiple numbers" - an actual String? or do you mean list?

Comment: I would recommend using `System.getProperty("line.separator");` instead of hard coding `\n` as the line feed.

Comment: Yeah it was an integer I converted to a string in order to display on the Text Area, I got it working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably using `System.out.println()` to print to console. The `System.out.println()` will add `'\n'` character to the end of each line for you.

But to output strings to `JTextArea` in same way use `jTextArea.append('\n');`.

Comment: Haha thank you, I knew I needed \n, just wasn't sure how to with append.

Answer (score 6):

put new line character which is  \n  at the end of the string

Answer (score 3):

Your JTextArea extends JTextComponent and thus has its own `read(...)` method that allows it to read in text files (among other things), understand them in an OS-dependent manner, and then display them, complete with new-lines. For example, please see [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9857723/522444) which is essentially,

```
     BufferedReader br = null;
     try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        textArea.read(br, null); // here we read in the text file
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     } finally {
        if (br != null) {
           try {
              br.close();
           } catch (IOException e) {}
        }
     }
```